# I developed music audio player, which play from assets folder, its works find in debug mode but when I build release apk its showing a grey color

Tags: flutter, dart

I develop a music player app in flutter, which I use listview builder to list the available music from assets folder, when I run it in debug mode its works proper but when build a release apk, its display a grey color without any content. I develop a music player app in flutter, which I use listview builder to list the available music from assets folder, when I run it in debug mode its works proper but when build a release apk, its display a grey color without any content.
. Below is my complete flutter code

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'durations.dart';
import 'surah.dart';

class PlayList extends StatefulWidget {
  const PlayList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PlayListState createState() => _PlayListState();
}

class _PlayListState extends State<PlayList> {

  bool isPlaying = false;
  bool isPause = false;
  bool isRepeat = false;
  bool isSheffle = false;
  bool isCompleted = false;
  Color iconColorR = Colors.white;
  Color iconColorS = Colors.white;
  int currentSuraIndex = -1;
  Duration _position = new Duration();
  Duration _musicLength = new Duration();
  AudioPlayer _player = AudioPlayer();
  PlayerState audioPlayerState = PlayerState.PAUSED;
  AudioCache cache = AudioCache();


  //PLAY AND PAUSE ICON BUTTON
  List<IconData> _icons = [
    Icons.play_circle_fill,
    Icons.pause_circle_filled
  ];

  List<IconData> _repeateIcons = [
    Icons.repeat,
    Icons.repeat_one_rounded
  ];

  //FUNCTION THAT FIRED WHEN PROGRAM IS RUN
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    cache = AudioCache(fixedPlayer: _player);
    _player.onDurationChanged.listen((Duration d) {
      setState((){
        _musicLength = d;
      });
    });
    _player.onAudioPositionChanged.listen((Duration p) {
      setState(() {
        _position = p;
      });
    });

    _player.onPlayerCompletion.listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        _position = Duration(seconds: 0);
        int rmd = Random().nextInt(112) + 1;
        if(isRepeat == true){
          isPlaying = true;
        } else if(isSheffle == true){
          play('quran/${rmd}.mp3');
          currentSuraIndex = rmd;
          isPlaying = true;
        } else {
          play('quran/${currentSuraIndex+1}.mp3');
          currentSuraIndex++;
        }
      });
    });
  }

  //FUNTION THAT FIRED WHEN PROGRAM IS CLOSED
  @override
  void dispose(){
    super.dispose();
    _player.release();
    _player.dispose();
    cache.loadedFiles.clear();

  }

  

  // PLAY FUNCTION
  play(path) async {
    await cache.play(path);
  }

  //FUNCTION THAT CREATE SLIDER
  Widget slider(){
    return Container(
      width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width) * 0.7,
      child: Slider(
            activeColor: Colors.white,
            inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
            min:0.0,
            value: _position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
            max: _musicLength.inSeconds.toDouble(),
            onChanged: (double value){
              setState(() {
                seekToSec(value.toInt());
                value = value;
              });
            },
      ),
    );
  }

  //FUNCTION THAT HANDLE SEEK IN AUDIO
  void seekToSec(int sec){
    Duration newPosition = Duration(seconds: sec);
    _player.seek(newPosition);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(
      "Surah Index",
      style: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        letterSpacing: 7.0,
      ),
      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
    ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange.shade900,
    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
    ),
    body:Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: suwaru.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
            return ListTile(
              tileColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
              selectedTileColor: Colors.white,
              leading: Text('${index+1} ',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 20.0
                  )),
              onTap:((){
                  play('quran/${index}.mp3');
                  setState(() {
                    isPlaying = true;
                    currentSuraIndex = index ;
                  });

              }),
              title: Text('${suwaru[index]}',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              subtitle: Text('${durations[index]}',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              trailing: Icon(index==currentSuraIndex&&isPlaying==true?_icons[1]:_icons[0],
                color: Colors.white
            )
            );
          }
      ),
    ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
            color: Colors.deepOrange.shade900,
            child: Container(
              height: screenHeight/6,
              child: Positioned(
                top: 0.0,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                            color: iconColorR,
                            iconSize: 30.0,
                            onPressed:((){
                              if(isRepeat == false){
                                _player.setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.LOOP);
                                setState(() {
                                  isRepeat = true;
                                  this.iconColorR = Colors.white;
                                });
                              } else if(isRepeat == true){
                                _player.setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.RELEASE);
                                setState(() {
                                  isRepeat = false;
                                  this.iconColorR = Colors.white;
                                });
                              }
                            }),
                            icon: isRepeat==false?Icon(_repeateIcons[0]):Icon(_repeateIcons[1]),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            iconSize: 30.0,
                            onPressed:((){
                              if(currentSuraIndex>1) {
                                play('quran/${currentSuraIndex-1}.mp3');
                                setState(() {
                                  isPlaying = true;
                                  currentSuraIndex--;
                                });
                              }else{
                                play('quran/0.mp3');
                              }
                            }),
                            icon: Icon(Icons.skip_previous_rounded)
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            iconSize: 30.0,
                            onPressed:((){
                              if(isPlaying==false) {
                                play('quran/${currentSuraIndex}.mp3');
                                setState(() {
                                  isPlaying = true;
                                });
                              }else if(isPlaying==true){
                                _player.pause();
                                setState(() {
                                  isPlaying = false;
                                });
                              }
                            }),
                            icon: isPlaying==false?Icon(_icons[0]):Icon(_icons[1]),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            iconSize: 30.0,
                            onPressed:((){
                              if(currentSuraIndex<114) {
                                play('quran/${currentSuraIndex+1}.mp3');
                                setState(() {
                                  isPlaying = true;
                                  currentSuraIndex++;
                                });
                              }else{
                                play('quran/0.mp3');
                                setState(() {
                                  isPlaying = true;
                                  currentSuraIndex = 0;
                                });
                              }
                            }),
                            icon: Icon(Icons.skip_next_rounded),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                            color: iconColorS,
                            iconSize: 30.0,
                            onPressed:((){
                              print(isSheffle);
                              if(isSheffle == false ){
                                setState((){
                                  isSheffle = true;
                                  this.iconColorS = Colors.grey;
                                });
                              } else if (isSheffle == true){
                                setState(() {
                                  isSheffle = false;
                                  this.iconColorS = Colors.white;
                                });
                              }
                            }),
                            icon: Icon(Icons.shuffle)
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),                
                     Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Text(_position.toString().split('.')[0],
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          slider(),
                          Text(_musicLength.toString().split('.')[0],
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    Text(currentSuraIndex<0?'No Audio Track':'${suwaru[currentSuraIndex].split('(')[0]}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10.0,letterSpacing: 5.0,),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Grey screen commonly comes due to your ui is not fine from somewhere. What I see so far is you have your body as container and then you have listview builder so try removing that container that is unnecessary + there seems issue in your bottom nav bar too you are using container and positioned then column thats a bad way to work around on the ui.  Look for error in debug mode if its giving some error then remove it as well then I'm sure you will have your screen back

Comment: Thank you sir, its works perfectly as I applied your response